# How to find index of a substring?

Tags: elixir

Looking for Elixir equivalent of Ruby's:

```
"john.snow@domain.com".index("@")         # => 9
"john.snow@domain.com".index("domain")    # => 10
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TL;DR: String.index/2 is intentionally missing because **smarter alternatives exist**. Very often **String.split/2** will solve the underlying problem - and with a way better performance.

- I assume we are talking UTF-8 strings here and expect to cleanly deal with non-ASCII characters.
- Elixir encourages fast code. It turns out that problems we usually try solve with String.index/2 can be solved in a much smarter way, vastly improving performance without degrading code readability.
- The smarter solution is to use String.split/2 and/or other similar String module functions. The String.split/2 works on a byte-level while still correctly handling graphemes. It can't go wrong because both arguments are Strings! The String.index/2 would have to work on a grapheme-level, slowly seeking throughout the String.
- For that reason the String.index/2 is unlikely be added to the language unless very compelling use cases come up that cannot be cleanly solved by existing functions.
- See also the elixir-lang-core discussion on that matter:
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/S0yrDxlJCss
- On a side note, Elixir is pretty unique in its mature Unicode support. While most languages work on a codepoint level (colloquially "characters"), Elixir works with a higher level concept of graphemes. Graphemes are what users perceive as one character (lets say its a more practical understanding of a "character"). Graphemes can contain more than one codepoint (which in turn can contain more than one byte).

Finally, if we really need the index:

```
case String.split("john.snow@domain.com", "domain", parts: 2) do
  [left, _] -> String.length(left)
  [_] -> nil
end
```

Comment: Has String.split/2 been deprecated? I only see split/1 and split/3 in the most recent docs.

Answer (score 21):

I don't think there's any Elixir wrapper for this, see [#1119](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/1119).

You can call [`:binary.match`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#match-2) directly until then:

```
iex(1)> :binary.match "john.snow@domain.com", "@"
{9, 1}
iex(2)> :binary.match "john.snow@domain.com", "domain"
{10, 6}
```

The return value is a tuple containing the index and the length of the match. You can extract just the index by piping into `|> elem(0)` or using pattern matching.

Note that `:binary.match` returns `:nomatch` if the substring isn't found in the string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Regex.run/3` and pass it `return: :index` as an option:

```
iex(5)> [{start, len}] = Regex.run(~r/abc/, " abc ", return: :index)
[{1, 3}]
```

Comment: Noting that you can use `Regex.scan/3` if you need to find all the indexes of a match

Answer (score 5):

You can get the byte index using [:binary.match/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#match-3)

```
{index, length} = :binary.match("aéiou", "o")    
{4, 1}
```

If you want the location in the string then use:

```
"aéiou" |> to_char_list() |> Enum.find_index(&(&1 == ?o))
3
```

The [String](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/String.html) module documentation explains the difference between byte length and string length.

Comment: Warning! :binary.match requires a "pattern" as its second argument, functioning much like regex. However, if the real intention is to get the real number of a repeated string then you should use "String.split" which, if implemented correctly, functions the same way as python's `str.find` and javascript's `str.indexOf`. Second, the Enum.find_index should be avoided as much as possible given that elixir has its recursive pattern and it's optimized that way. It is a fast approach though if you don't want to overthink that much.

Answer (score 1):

```
# index (as INSTR from basic...)

...
 import IO, except: [inspect: 1]  
 puts index "algopara ver", "ver" 

 def index( mainstring, searchstring) do 
   tuple = (:binary.match mainstring, searchstring)
   if tuple === :nomatch do 
      0 
   else 
      elem(tuple,0) 
   end  
 end 
... 

9
```