# Elixir - Check if string includes a sub-string

Tags: elixir

How to check if a String includes another String in Elixir? This is different from [How to find index of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551072/how-to-find-index-of-a-substring).

Something like:

```elixir
String.includes("hello", "lo")
#=> true
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> [**String.contains?(string, contents)**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#contains?/2)
>
> Checks if string contains any of the given contents.

**Example:**

```elixir
iex> String.contains? "elixir of life", "of"
true
iex> String.contains? "elixir of life", ["life", "death"]
true
iex> String.contains? "elixir of life", ["venus", "mercury"]
false
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `=~`:

```
"elixir of life" =~ "of"
# true
```

or in tests with assertions:

```
assert "elixir of life" =~ "of"
```

or with a regular expression:

```
"elixir of life" =~ ~r/of/
# true
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#=~/2): 
Matches the term on the left against the regular expression or string on the right.

Returns true if left matches right (if it's a regular expression) or contains right (if it's a string).