# elixir String.split/3: how to tell which character was matched

Tags: string, elixir

I'm trying to build a parser using `String.split/3` as an exercise just to see if I can make it faster than classic recursive pattern matching (by effectively allocating fewer strings), but I'm having trouble making it correct.

I need to be able to split binaries in 2 parts at either a `{` or a `}`, and `String.split(str, ["{", "}"], parts: 2)` does exactly that of course. My problem is that the result contains only the list `[part1, part2]` but it does not contain the character it matched on, which I need because it affects the behavior of the parser.

My first instinct was to make my own `index/2` but after reading up some more it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35587943/289992) like a [bad idea](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/S0yrDxlJCss)

Is there a better alternative for my use case? I'd like to go through the string as few times as possible, creating new strings only at `{` and `}` boundaries.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Do you only want to split into two binaries (at the first occurrence of `{` or `}`) or was that just an example and you want to split at _every_ occurrence of `{` and `}`?

Comment: Yes, I only need left and right parts (1st ocurrence), I just need to know what it was that matched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want to split at the first occurrence, I'd suggest using `:binary.match/3` and `:binary.part/3` here. `:binary.match/3` returns a tuple of index of the match and the length of the match on success, which can then be used with `:binary.part/2` to split the binary.

```
defmodule A do
  def split(binary) do
    case :binary.match(binary, ["{", "}"]) do
      {start, length} ->
        before = :binary.part(binary, 0, start)
        match = :binary.part(binary, start, length)
        after_ = :binary.part(binary, start + length, byte_size(binary) - (start + length))
        {before, match, after_}
      :nomatch -> nil
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect A.split("foo { bar") |> IO.inspect
IO.inspect A.split("foo } bar") |> IO.inspect
IO.inspect A.split("foo + bar") |> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
{"foo ", "{", " bar"}
{"foo ", "{", " bar"}
{"foo ", "}", " bar"}
{"foo ", "}", " bar"}
nil
nil
```

This implementation goes through the string only once, in the `:binary.match/3` call. All other functions and operations used are `O(1)`.

I've used a similar method in an XML parser I was working on and it provided a huge speed up compared to recursive pattern matching on the binary.

Edit: you can use pattern matching to make this code way shorter, and I'm pretty sure with the exact same performance as above:

```
defmodule A do
  def split(binary) do
    case :binary.match(binary, ["{", "}"]) do
      {start, length} ->
        <<a::binary-size(start), b::binary-size(length), c::binary>> = binary
        {a, b, c}
      :nomatch -> nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I was also leaning towards `binary_part` since "{" and "}" are ascii chars. From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 "Backward compatibility: One-byte codes are used for the ASCII values 0 through 127,...Bytes in this range are not used anywhere else... as it will not accidentally see those ASCII characters in the middle of a multi-byte character."

Comment: Yep, this will not mess up UTF-8 encoded binaries in any way.

Comment: Please check out my edit for a much much more elegant solution! If you're benchmarking this, please let me know how the two versions compare.

Comment: Yep, intend on benchmarking and blogging the results :)

Comment: the second version is marginally faster besides being prettier https://nerds.stoiximan.gr/2017/05/24/pattern-matching-and-state-machines/

Comment: Hmm, your site's Cloudflare settings have apparently blocked my country: "The owner of this website (nerds.stoiximan.gr) has banned the country or region your IP address is in (IN) from accessing this website."

Comment: sorry about that. Please use this link until we can get a fix in place https://github.com/StoiximanServices/blog/blob/master/pattern_matching_and_state_machines/POST.md

Answer (score 3):

Dig a little deeper in the [String.split docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3) and use the `include_captures` option.

`iex> String.split("Foo{bar}", ~r({|}), [include_captures: true, trim: true])`
`["Foo", "{", "bar", "}"]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it uses the regex engine underneath and i'd like to avoid using it. Good catch though, I completely missed that!